# is there a more efficient way to get all the indices of element that has one euclidean distance to a specific element inside a matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a matrix.

```
1 2 1
1 1 0
0 1 1
```

I am tring to get all the indices of digit 1 that directly linked to digit 2, i.e. [0,0], [0,2] and [1,1]

```
ds = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
p0 = np.where(ds == 2)
p1 = np.where(ds == 1)
d1 = np.array(p1) - np.array(p0)
idx = np.where(np.linalg.norm(d1,axis=0, keepdims=True) == 1)[1]
np.take(p1, idx, axis=1 )
```

if there are more than one 2s, the neighbors of each 2 need to be stored separately.

This piece of code works though, I would like to know if is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code won't work if there are more than one 2s in the array, so you need a more general approach.

Based on your expectations two indices are neighbor if they have one axis in common and different in another axis by 1 unit.

```
    X
  X O X
    X
```

Now if you have an array as following:

```
In [87]: arr # I changed the value of [2, 2] index to 2
Out[87]: 
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

You can do the find the expected indies in a vectorized way as follows:

```
In [88]: one_indices = np.argwhere(arr==1)

In [89]: two_indices = np.argwhere(arr==2)

In [90]: x, y = np.where(two_indices[:, 0][:,None] == one_indices[:, 0])

In [91]: neighbor_on_row = one_indices[y[np.where(np.abs(one_indices[:, 1][y] - two_indices[:, 1][x]) == 1)[0]]]

In [92]: neighbor_on_row
Out[92]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1]])

In [93]: x, y = np.where(two_indices[:, 1][:,None] == one_indices[:, 1])

In [94]: neighbor_on_col = one_indices[y[np.where(np.abs(one_indices[:, 0][y] - two_indices[:, 0][x]) == 1)[0]]]

In [95]: neighbor_on_col
Out[95]: array([[1, 1]])
```

And finally:

```
In [103]: np.concatenate((neighbor_on_row, neighbor_on_col))
Out[103]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use morphological [dilation](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/dilate.htm) using `open-cv` library I tried your method and the one I wrote with that operation and mine was twice faster. I also tried `scipy` [implementation of dilation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation) but it took more time than your implementation.
If you can use open-cv then this code maybe is useful for you:

```
kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.uint8) 

def get_twoes_neighbor2(ds, kernel):
    img = (ds == 2).astype(np.uint8)
    img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1) 
    neighbors = (ds == 1) & img_dilation
    return np.array(np.where(neighbors == 1))
```